# Passing Model property from Jquery Ajax call to Controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

**Question background:**

I'm simply trying to pass a number of properties from a view (which has had a model passed to it from its associated controller) to another method on the controller.

**The code:**

Ajax call:

```
$("#myLink").click(function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddToCart")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {

                "qty": $('#productQty').val(),
                "name": $('#productName').text(),
                "price": $('#productPrice').text(),
                "brand": $('#productBrand').text(),

                //Image property is NOT being sent.
                "image" : $(@Model.Image).val()
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to set a property of the model passed to the view to the `"image"` data propety of the Ajax call.

This is the method on the controller that is being called:

```
public void AddToCart(string qty, string name, string price, string brand, string image)
{
   //Logic.

}
```

**The issue:**

Currently I can't seem to find a way of passing the 'Image' property. I have tried setting it to a 'var' but it is still passed as null.

**How can I send this property staright from the passed model when it is not set to a HTML element?**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `@Html.HiddenFor()`?

Comment: You can create a hidden field and set the image property as its `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the @Model.Image property as a jQuery selector. That doesn't really make sense if you really don't have form elements that match the selector (`<input id="input1" ...>`  would match if the value of @Model.Image was "#input1")